# iPhone SDK: handling keybaord appearance

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I need to move UI elements of my view controller when keyboard appears. I do this by registering for the keyboard notifications in my app delegate:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:observer
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:observer
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

and then handling notification as prescribed by Apple (I have similar code for keyboard was shown) to scroll the view up and down:

`- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGRect viewFrame = [self.view   frame]; 
    viewFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - TOOLBAR_HEIGHT;
    self.view.frame = viewFrame;
}`

**So far so good. Now problem description:**

When I execute this code to show OS 3.0 specific message UI:

`MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

and when keyboard shows in the actual mail UI, I still get keyboard notification which scrolls my view and therefore breaking my UI (note that mail controller takes entire screen and my view is not even visible at this point).

I was hoping to temporary disable keyboard notification, so my scrolling code would not get called with this line:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

But it does not help, keyboard even still get posted.

What should I do avoid reacting on the keyboard when it created by the message UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `BOOL` property or instance variable: `careAboutKeyboard` that's accessible to both your `keyboardWasShown:` and `keywardWasHidden:` methods, likely in the view controller those methods are in.

Have it set to `YES` when in the `viewWillAppear` method, and set to `NO` when you show the mail view and in `viewWillDisappear`.

Then put all of your scrolling logic in an if block:

```
if(careAboutKeyboard) {
    // Scrolling logic
}
```

Comment: Great mind think alike! After I posted this, I was thinking that this apporach would be something to try.
Could you clarify what is "atomic" property? I was thkning just adding BOOL variable to class, not even a property.

Comment: If your application is single threaded, you don't have to worry about atomicity. Actually, since only the event thread should be calling the methods I named, just forget I even said atomic. I've edited my answer.